# Globalization in Asp.Net MVC 2.0 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I am working on asp.net mvc 2.0 web application in which I want to give the support of multiple language. Currently application run in English language but I want there will be a dropdown list of languages and if the user select French then my application language should convert into french language. Any idea how can I achieve this or any tutorial, please share with me.

Regards

Comment: Here is a tutorial: http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/10/ASPNET-MVC-Simplified-Localization-via-ViewEngines.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ASP.NET MVC code you can take advantage of System.Globalization class which will use App_LocalResources for all the strings. There are several things to understand before making a decision on what to choose:

The URL Routing is used commonly and it is a very simple and very powerful way of storing it in URL using routing mechanism.
http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html

You can choose "Localization using Session" not a popular option but chosen by some and in the article below Session is used for storing current culture to localize the content:

http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html

The SO discussion does talks the same:
[Localization & Globalization in asp.net mvc 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660688/localization-globalization-in-asp-net-mvc-2-0)