Replace existing action routes in ASP.NET Core
I have my ASP.NET Core 8 project that references to external project that contains the following controller:
public class AccountController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

where:

AccountController.Login is mapped to route /Login
AccountController.ChangePassword is mapped to route /ChangePassword

I would like to replace these routes in Startup.cs of my ASP.NET Core 8 project, so that the routes support multiple cultures as follows:
AccountController.Login -> /en/login, /it/login

AccountController.ChangePassword -> /en/change-password, /it/cambia-password

Could someone provide guidance or an example on how to configure this in Startup.cs file?

You should consider reading this post and see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683404/asp-net-mvc-localized-routes-and-the-default-language-for-the-user
You can't necessarily RegisterRoutes as that is .NET Framework, but you can define a default route in Startup.cs and add language as a route parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0

What's your routes configuration in the ASP.NET Core 8 project to access controller methods from the external project? Could you provide the code of it, and the framework of the external project? I want to test it with more specific information.

To support multiple cultures by changing the routes, you can read about this document: Apply the RouteDataRequest CultureProvider
Below is a sample demo:
In the asp.net core mvc test project:
1.Create the resource file first, refer to Resource files
The name of resource file must match the view page (my test view: Views\Home\Index.cshtml)

2.Configure in the program.cs:
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

builder.Services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();


builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("it")
                    // Add more cultures as needed
                };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("it");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider()
                    {
                        RouteDataStringKey = "culture",
                        Options = options // This line ensures options.DefaultRequestCulture is used
                    }
                };
});


app.UseRequestLocalization();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "localized-login",
        pattern: "{culture}/{action=Index}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, // In your code, you should change to `controller = "Account" `
        constraints: new { culture = new RegexRouteConstraint(@"^[a-zA-Z]{2}(-[a-zA-Z]{2})?$") }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

In the external project:
3.Inject IStringLocalizer in the Controller:
private readonly IStringLocalizer<HomeController> _localizer;

public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<HomeController> localizer)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
}

public IActionResult Login()
{

    ViewData["Title"] = _localizer["LoginPageTitle"];
    ViewData["ButtonText"] = _localizer["LoginButtonText"];

    return View();
}

4.Inject the IViewLocalizer in the Login view page:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

<h1>@Localizer["LoginPageTitle"]</h1>
<button>@Localizer["LoginButtonText"]</button>

Test result:


